# Trying to add 180 to total when weekday is a friday or saturday

Tags: vb.net, date

Hello I am trying to make it so that while day is less than departure date, and if the day is a friday or a saturday, instead of just adding 160 total for each day, it would add 180 for just friday and saturday. I am stuck on the if statement for when day would be a friday or saturday.

This is my code:

```
    Dim arrival As Date = CDate(txtArrivalDate.Text)
    Dim Departure As Date = CDate(txtDepartureDate.Text)
    Dim Days As Long = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, arrival, Departure)
    Dim Total As Long = 160 * Days
    Dim Day As Date = arrival

    While (Day <= Departure)
        If CBool(Day.DayOfWeek.Friday And Day.DayOfWeek.Saturday) Then
            Total += 180
        End If
        Day = Day.AddDays(1)
    End While
```

Comment: Is this pseudo code or maybe VB.Net or something because currently it doesn't compile in the VBA Editor

Answer (score 1):

Your code is `vb.net`, not `vba`. ;-)

This is the correct condition, if I understood you correct:

```
If Day.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Friday Or Day.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday Then
```

Comment: ah sorry yes it is vb.net sorry for that and thanks for the answer!